# Upgrade to Flex SDK 4.5.1 from 4.1.0 causes namespace compile errors for certain mx components

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flash-builder, flexmojos

I have a Flash builder project that I am migrating from SDK 4.1.0 to 4.5.1.  This has been a relatively easy change (we are using maven for our builds, and were able to get a successful build after updating to the 4.5.1 dependencies).

As said, the project builds fine with maven and flexmojos.  The issue is when opening the project in flash builder.  The maven project is imported and then set as a flex project by running the maven `flexmojos:flexbuilder` build command.

The issue lies when certain mx components that are specified with the s: namespace are no longer accepted by the IDE, and result in an error.  For example, for the following to compile:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>
```

`s:State` must be changed to the `mx` namespace:

```
<s:states>
    <mx:State name="normal" />
    <mx:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>
```

This is just one example, and only happens for certain spark-namespaced components.  Why is this?  **Why does this compile OK with Flex SDK 4.1.0 but not with Flex SDK 4.5.1, and what is the cause of the necessary namespace change?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the same problems using FlexMojos because it seems that Adobe did a little trick of specifying the spark namespace for mx components (like State and Spacer).

Also, if you're using `flexmojos:flexbuilder`, it means you're also using an old version of FlexMojos (3.8?).  There's version 4.0 now (RC2), however, the flexbuilder goal has been removed for now.

Anywho, back to your question, I see it the other way in my project (s:Spacer works in Flash Builder, not in FlexMojos).  Personally, I feel that these namespace shouldn't intersect and as a developer it's easier to just specify the exact namespace and not bother with the namespace trickery.

Comment: While it's comforting to hear that I am not the only one seeing the issue, it'd be nice to have confirmation of the exact change adobe made to their components that cause it.  Are the namespace changes apparent because adobe was "translating" the xmlns namespaces before, or was there an actual component namespace change?